# How to fetch iOS Contacts more quickly using Apple's Contacts framework having long list of contacts?

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactstore

I am using **CNContacts** to fetch phonebook contacts in my iOS device.

When I have a small number of contacts in my phone (say, 50) the contacts are fetched easily.

However, when I have a lot of contacts (say 500-700) it hangs/waits for a long time to fetch these contacts from iOS phonebook into my App's array.

Previously I used https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook which was a fast library for the previous Apple framework, but now I am using the latest Apple framework.

My code to fetch contacts is ....

```
#pragma mark - Get All Contacts....

-(void)getAllContactsWithNewFrameworkOfApple {

    NSMutableArray *_contactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
    if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app previously was refused permissions to contacts; Please go to settings and grant permission to this app so it can use contacts" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        //        [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        return;
    }

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        // make sure the user granted us access

        if (!granted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // user didn't grant access;
                // so, again, tell user here why app needs permissions in order  to do it's job;
                // this is dispatched to the main queue because this request could be running on background thread
            });
            return;
        }

        NSError *fetchError;
        CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey,CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]];

        BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {

            [_contactsArray addObject:contact];
            NSLog(@"I am %@", _contactsArray);

        }];

        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
        }else {

                        NSLog(@"End with Success %@", _contactsArray);
            [self finalUsage:_contactsArray];

        }

    }];



}
```

I was trying to fetch contacts in batches of 20, reloading the table each time. However here it can't reload within the dispatch thread, or simply crashes.

How do I improve this code to fetch contacts quickly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can get the contacts in a child thread, but when reloading table, it should run in the main thread. It crashes due to reloading table in the **child** thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Toro mentioned, the `requestAccessForEntityType: completionHandler:` method is not running on the main (UI) thread. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CNContactStore/requestAccessForEntityType:completionHandler:) you can see it mentions that:

> Users are able to grant or deny access to contact data on a
>   per-application basis. Request access to contact data by calling
>   requestAccessForEntityType:completionHandler: method. This will not
>   block your application while the user is being asked for permission.
>   The user will only be prompted the first time access is requested; any
>   subsequent CNContactStore calls will use the existing permissions. T**he
>   completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue**. It is recommended
>   that you use CNContactStore instance methods in this completion
>   handler instead of the UI main thread. This method is optional when
>   CNContactStore is used in the background thread. If this method is not
>   used, CNContactStore may block your application while the user is
>   asked for access permission.

So any updates you want to do in the UI, you'll have to do on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //Update UI on the Main thread, like reloading a UITableView
});
```