# CNContact fetching should be faster

Tags: swift, cncontact

I am fetching contact from CNContact and it took .30 seconds to show thousands of contact in UI. My client want me to reduce time upto 0.01 second. He gave me example of Telegram app. Can any one help

Ex Code :

typealias ContactsHandler = (_ contacts : [CNContact] , _ error : NSError?) -> Void

extension CDContactsPickerVC {

```
func getContacts(_ completion:  @escaping ContactsHandler) {
    if contactsStore == nil {
        //ContactStore is control for accessing the Contacts
        contactsStore = CNContactStore()
    }
    let error = NSError(domain: "CDContactPickerErrorDomain", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No Contacts Access"])

    switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts) {
    case CNAuthorizationStatus.denied, CNAuthorizationStatus.restricted:
        //User has denied the current app to access the contacts.

        let productName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"]!

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unable to access contacts", message: "\(productName) does not have access to contacts. Kindly enable it in privacy settings ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {  action in
            completion([], error)
        })
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case CNAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        //This case means the user is prompted for the first time for allowing contacts
        contactsStore?.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (granted, error) -> Void in
            //At this point an alert is provided to the user to provide access to contacts. This will get invoked if a user responds to the alert
            if  (!granted ){
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    completion([], error! as NSError?)
                })
            }
            else{
                self.getContacts(completion)
            }
        })

    case  CNAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        //Authorization granted by user for this app.
        var contactsArray = [CNContact]()

        let contactFetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: allowedContactKeys())

        do {
            try contactsStore?.enumerateContacts(with: contactFetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
                //Ordering contacts based on alphabets in firstname
                contactsArray.append(contact)
                var key: String = "#"
                //If ordering has to be happening via family name change it here.
                if let firstLetter = contact.givenName[0..<1] , firstLetter.containsAlphabets() {
                    key = firstLetter.uppercased()
                }
                var contacts = [CNContact]()

                if let segregatedContact = self.orderedContacts[key] {
                    contacts = segregatedContact
                }


                var identifierArray = [String]()
                for contactDict in self.orderedContacts {
                    let contactArray = contactDict.value as [CNContact]
                    for cnObj in contactArray {
                        identifierArray.append(cnObj.identifier)
                    }
                }

                if identifierArray.contains(contact.identifier) {
                    // do nothing
                }else {
                    contacts.append(contact)
                    self.orderedContacts[key] = contacts
                }


            })
            self.sortedContactKeys = Array(self.orderedContacts.keys).sorted(by: <)
            if self.sortedContactKeys.first == "#" {
                self.sortedContactKeys.removeFirst()
                self.sortedContactKeys.append("#")
            }

            completion(contactsArray, nil)
        }
            //Catching exception as enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest can throw errors
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}

func allowedContactKeys() -> [CNKeyDescriptor]{
    //We have to provide only the keys which we have to access. We should avoid unnecessary keys when fetching the contact. Reducing the keys means faster the access.
    return [CNContactNamePrefixKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
            CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
            CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    ]
}

// MARK: - Contact Operations

open func reloadContacts() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.getContacts( {(contacts, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.emptyContactLabel.isHidden = contacts.count > 0 ? true : false
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
                self.updateContactsInLocalDB(contacts: contacts)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Hi Singh,

I am new user. the code is not comming in comment box.

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: Hi Singh can u please check now. I have edited the question

Comment: Please check once the Telegram app. My client just want like Telegram functionality. Its too much fast. With in a second it loads thousands of contact.
My client have approx 30,000 contact which took approx .30 seconds. But he need 0.01 second

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604817/how-to-fetch-ios-contacts-more-quickly-using-apples-contacts-framework-having-l

Comment: Thanks Singh, i have already implement this scenario. Need more refine code. Like Telegram app.